# Ogre::SceneManager::setAmbientLight doese not work

Tags: directx, game-engine, ogre

i am building the wiki [Advanced Ogre Framework](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Advanced%20Ogre%20Framework),
then i find that the Ogre::SceneManager::setAmbientLight() does not work at all.
i find nothing useful after google, anyone can give me some idea?
the code is like this:

```
m_pSceneMgr = OgreFramework::getSingletonPtr()->m_pRoot->createSceneManager(ST_GENERIC, "GameSceneMgr");
m_pSceneMgr->setAmbientLight(Ogre::ColourValue(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i figure it out bymyslef,
in the framework,  i call `setAmbientLight()` before these code:

```
DotSceneLoader* pDotSceneLoader = new DotSceneLoader();
pDotSceneLoader->parseDotScene("CubeScene.xml", "General", m_pSceneMgr, m_pSceneMgr->getRootSceneNode());
delete pDotSceneLoader;
```

there is a node in the CubeScene.xml set the ambient color again, which is (0,0,0), so my call can not work then.